# using one of 2 DNSs differentiated by requested domain

Tags: linux, ubuntu, domain-name-system, resolv.conf, split-dns

I'm using some sort of a dns-proxy service (the details aren't clear but as far as I understand it works by resolving the the domain into a cloud based proxy server and returning it's address whilst configuring it to forward my requests to the actual domain)

what I want to do is to use said DNS only when necessary (i.e. when accessing a specific domain) otherwise use the default resolving method.

I've gone over the resolv.conf manual and seen the post [Configuring nameserver per domain?](https://serverfault.com/questions/173089/configuring-nameserver-per-domain). the OP seems to want something similar.

Is there a simple method for achieving this? I think split DNS (from the little I understood) is quite the overkill (if its the only way, I will appreciate some sort of guide please).

the OS is Linux Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: I think I can explain how to do this by using a BIND instance running locally, and using 127.0.0.1 in resolv.conf, but this is rather overkill. Are you able to explain which dns-proxy service you're using? As I don't see myself why setting this service up for one domain would also force it to be used for other domains, each domain has its own set of authoritative nameservers so the DNS records can be totally different for each; your question doesn't make sense to me in the way that you've worded it.

Comment: Actually, I think I now understand what you mean. The answer below, and setting up BIND as a local, forwarding-only resolver, is the only solution I can think of right now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to use a specific DNS for a specific domain?](http://serverfault.com/questions/391914/is-there-a-way-to-use-a-specific-dns-for-a-specific-domain)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple

run the following commands

```
sudo apt-get install dnsmasq
```

then edit `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` (with `sudo`!)

find the following string in the file

```
#server=/localnet/192.168.0.1
```

and add afterwards

```
server=/your_forward_domain/you_custom_DNS_ip
```

for all the other domains it will automatically use the same DNS as your system used before.

don't forget to

```
sudo /etc/init.d/dnsmasq restart
```

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a local DNS resolver.

Then, if you need to use specific resolver for a domain, just forward DNS query to the resolver by setting a [forward zone](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch4/#forwarding) in your bind configuration :

```
zone "example.com" IN {
    type forward;
    forwarders {10.0.0.1; 10.0.0.2;};
};

zone "example2.com" IN {
    type forward;
    forwarders {10.0.0.3; 10.0.0.4;};
};
```